# Count text fields T-SQL

Tags: sql-server

```
Select myColumn, count(*) totalcount
from myTable
group by myColumn
having count(*) >1
order by count(*) desc;
```

The following works for counting integer fields, but not for text fields.  How do I need to modify it so that it will work for text fields?

Thanks to all for their help!

Comment: Wanting to group by field values of  `text` datatype sounds quite unusual. What length/type of contents do they have? Also version of SQL Server?

Comment: you mean text datatype or values?

Comment: Why do you say it doesn't work for text fields? do you get an error? It seems perfectly valid to me...

Comment: I mean text data types.  I have a table with alphanumerics of 3-5 digits.  I'm getting an error when I try to make myColumn a primary key because it says there are duplicates.  However I imported this data straight from Excel and it found no duplicates.  So I'm trying to get the codes that are 'repeated' so I can see what the deal is.

Comment: @AlejoBrz - `The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator.` probably. Darrin - You have the wrong datatype. `text` is not suitable for this. Use `[var]char(5)`instead.

Comment: @DarrinCecil - If that column is 3-5 digits, then why is it not `NUMERIC` or even `VARCHAR(5)`?, `TEXT` is a really bad choice for that column

Comment: @ Martin Smith, you are correct.  Is there an easy, quick way to get a count of all number of times a particular string appears in a column?

Comment: @Lamak I'm very much still learning :).  I was under the impression to avoid varchar at any costs, but I cast the key as varchar and it returned no duplicates so I'm guessing that was the problem :)

Comment: *What* is the exact datatype: this is crucial to the answer...

Comment: The data type was *text*.  As recommended, I changed the datatype to *varchar(5)* and it worked perfectly.

Comment: text hasn't been recommended since sql server 2000...

Comment: @gbn this is why I come to SO, so I can get real-world advice from professionals.  I'm still learning :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you have trailing (or leading) spaces which are different values to trimmed values...

And you mean text values not datatype...

Comment: I think you might be right.  There should be no dupes, but it's saying there is.  Must be whitespace.

Comment: @DarrinCecil - I'm still confused about the actual; datatype. Are you saying that you don't get an error with the `group by` just wrong results? In the comments to your Q you indicate that you are talking about the datatype called `text`.

Comment: @MartinSmith I got the error "The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator".  I think I found the answer I needed here.  Thanks to all :)

Answer (score 2):

For SQL Server 2005+, you could:

```
SELECT CAST(myColumn AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), COUNT(*) totalcount
    FROM myTable
    GROUP BY CAST(myColumn AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
    HAVING COUNT(*) >1
    ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```